# Fieldset está dentro de outro, como arrumar?

Tags: html, html5, formulário

Estou fazendo um formulário e coloquei 4 fieldsets nele, o 1° para Pessoa, o 2° para Endereço, 3° para Dados médicos e o 4° para Comentários Extras.
Acontece que quando abro ele no Google Chrome, o 3° fieldset fica dentro do 2° fieldset, de tal modo que não aparece nem o Label do 3° fieldset, eu precisava separá-los mas não estou conseguindo.

- Já troquei a ordem dos fieldset, coloquei o 3° no lugar do 2° e eles FUNCIONARAM, porém escondeu o 4°.
- Percebi que o 2° fieldset(Endereço) está sempre "comendo" os fieldsets abaixo dele.

Segue meu código HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Formulario.css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Formulario.js"></script>
    <title>Cadastro</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <h1 id="titulo">Cadastro Vacinação</h1>
        <p id="subtitulo">Complete atenciosamente suas informações</p>
        <br>
    </div>

    <form>
        <fieldset class="grupo1">
            <div>
                <label for="nome"><Strong>Nome:*</Strong></label>
                <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" required>
            </div>

            <div class="campo">
                <label for="sobrenome"><Strong>Sobrenome:*</Strong></label>
                <input type="text" name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome" required>
            </div>

            <div class="campo">
                <label for="idade"><Strong>Data de Nascimento:*</Strong></label>
                <input type="text" name="idade" id="idade" maxlenght="10" onkeypress="mascaraData(this)" required>
            </div>

            <div class="campo">
                <label for="cel"><Strong>Tel(Celular):*</Strong></label>
                <input type="text" name="cel" id="cel" onkeypress="mascara(this, mascaraCel);" onblur="mascara(this, mascaraCel);" required>
            </div>

            <div class="campo">
                <label for="email"><Strong>E-Mail:*</Strong></label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
            </div>

            <div class="campo">
                <label for="cpf"><Strong>CPF:*</Strong></label>
                <input type="text" id="cpf" onkeyup="cpfCheck(this)" maxlength="14" onkeydown="javascript:fMasc(this, mCPF);" required>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="grupo2">
            <div class="campo">
                <label for="cep"><Strong>CEP:*</Strong></label>
                <input id="cep" name="cep" type="text" placeholder="01010-100" value="" maxlenght="9" onblur="pesquisacep(this.value);" required />
                <label for="rua"><Strong>Logradouro:*</Strong></label>
                <input id="rua" name="rua" type="text" placeholder="Rua das Nações" required />
                <label for="numero"><Strong>Número:</Strong></label>
                <input id="numero" type="text" />
                <label for="complemento"><Strong>Complemento:</Strong></label>
                <input id="complemento" type="text" />
                <label for="bairro"><Strong>Bairro:*</Strong></label>
                <input id="bairro" name="bairro" type="text" placeholder="Jardim das Nações" required />
                <label for="cidade"><Strong>Cidade:*</Strong></label>
                <input id="cidade" name="cidade" type="text" placeholder="São Paulo">
                <label for="uf"><Strong>Estado:*</Strong></label>
                <select id="uf" name="uf">
                <option selected disabled value="">Selecione:</option>
                    <option value="AC">Acre (AC)</option>
                    <option value="AL">Alagoas (AL)</option>
                    <option value="AP">Amapá (AP)</option>
                    <option value="AM">Amazonas (AM)</option>
                    <option value="BA">Bahia (BA)</option>
                    <option value="CE">Ceará (CE)</option>
                    <option value="DF">Distrito Federal (DF)</option>
                    <option value="ES">Espírito Santo (ES)</option>
                    <option value="GO">Goiás (GO)</option>
                    <option value="MA">Maranhão (MA)</option>
                    <option value="MT">Mato Grosso (MT)</option>
                    <option value="MS">Mato Grosso do Sul (MS)</option>
                    <option value="MG">Minas Gerais (MG)</option>
                    <option value="PA">Pará (PA)</option>
                    <option value="PB">Paraíba (PB)</option>
                    <option value="PR">Paraná (PR)</option>
                    <option value="PE">Pernambuco (PE)</option>
                    <option value="PI">Piauí (PI)</option>
                    <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro (RJ)</option>
                    <option value="RN">Rio Grande do Norte (RN)</option>
                    <option value="RS">Rio Grande do Sul (RS)</option>
                    <option value="RO">Rondônia (RO)</option>
                    <option value="RR">Roraima (RR)</option>
                    <option value="SC">Santa Catarina (SC)</option>
                    <option value="SP">São Paulo (SP)</option>
                    <option value="SE">Sergipe (SE)</option>
                    <option value="TO">Tocantins (TO)</option>
                    </selection>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="grupo3">
            <div class="campo">
                <label><Strong>Qual seu tipo sanguíneo?</Strong></label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sg" value="NS" checked>Não Sei
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sg" value="A+">A+
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sg" value="A-">A-
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sg" value="B+">B+
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sg" value="B-">B-
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sg" value="AB+">AB+
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sg" value="AB-">AB-
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sg" value="O+">O+
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sg" value="O-">O-
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="campo">
                <label for="sus"><Strong>Carteira SUS:</Strong></label>
                <input type="number" name="sus" id="sus">
            </div>

            <div class="campo">
                <label><Strong>Se vacinou nos últimos 7 meses?</Strong></label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sete" value="sim" checked>Sim
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sete" id="nao">Não
                </label>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="grupo4">
            <div class="campo">
                <br>
                <label><Strong>Está sentindo algum sintoma estranho? Se sim, nos conte.</Strong></label>
                <textarea row="6" style="width: 26em" name="sintoma" id="sintoma"></textarea>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <button class="conclu" type="submit">Concluído</button>
        <input class="print" type="button" value="Imprimir" onClick="window.print()" />
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Erro de digitação: dê uma olhada no ` <fieldset class="grupo2">` em `<select id="uf" name="uf">` você fecha com a tag `</selection>`

Comment: Valeu Augusto, passou despercebido. Grato!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Deveria fechar o elemento `select` corretamente

onde você tem:

```
</selection>
```

Substitua por:

```
</select>
```

Comment: nossa, passou despercebido TOTAL, muito orbigado!!